# Return objects in array with 'true' parameters

Tags: arrays, angularjs, foreach, push, truthiness

I have a `teamDetails` array, within which is a `squad` array, within which are `player` objects. Each player object has an `injured` property which contains the value `"true"` or `"false"`.

I want to write a function that loops through the array returning only players whose injured property evaluates to true.

This is what I have so far (not working):

```
$scope.injuredPlayerSearch = function() {
  var injuredPlayers = [];

  $scope.teamDetails.squad.forEach(function(o) {
      if (o[injured] === true) {
        injuredPlayers.push(o)
      }
    });

  return injuredPlayers;
}
```

I can't see what's wrong with this. If anyone can, would appreciate some help.

Comment: Do you have an example of the actual data?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to write any function. angular is there for you.

```
var injuredPlayers = $filter('filter')($scope.teamDetails.squad, {injured:true}, true);
```

Here $filter is angular filter. Do dependency inject to your controler or sevice where you are using.

For more about angular filter refer [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

**Note**: 2nd true is for strict type checking. it is equivalent to  **`injured===true`**

**EDIT**

For showing it to directly on view angular has much better solution.

```
{{teamDetails.squad | filter:{injured:true}:true}}
```

For use in view no need any dependency injection or controller.

Comment: Ok, that looks like what I'm after. So if I put this in my controller... `$scope.injuredPlayers = $filter('filter')($scope.teamDetails.squad, {injured:true}, true);`, and then call `{{injuredPlayers}}` in my view, would that work?

Comment: You can directly use it on view if you just need to show only in view. Updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the iteration is within an `array of array` this is the correct implementation:

```
$scope.injuredPlayerSearch = function() {
  var injuredPlayers = [];

  $scope.teamDetails.forEach(function(t){
    t.squad.forEach(function(o) {
      if (o[injured] === true) {
        injuredPlayers.push(o)
      }
    });
  });

  return injuredPlayers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filter` to return players who are injured:

```
$scope.injuredPlayerSearch = function() {
    return $scope.teamDetails.squad.filter(function(o) {
        return o[injured];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   var injuredPlayers = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.teamDetails.squad,function(s){
     if (s.injured === true) {
      injuredPlayers.push(s)
     }
  })
 return injuredPlayers;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the javascript [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
  var players = [{ id : 0 , injured : true},
                { id : 1 , injured : false},
                { id : 2 , injured : false},
                { id : 3 , injured : true},
                { id : 4 , injured : true}];

  var injuredPlayers = players.filter(filterByInjured)

  function filterByInjured(player) {
      if ('injured' in player && typeof(player.injured) === 'boolean' && player.injured === true) {
          return true;
      }
  }

  console.log(injuredPlayers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You did everything correct just left something

```
$scope.injuredPlayerSearch = function() {
     var injuredPlayers = [];

     angular.forEach($scope.teamDetails.squad,function(o) {
          if (o[injured] === true) {
                 injuredPlayers.push(o)
          }
     });

     return injuredPlayers;
}
```